# document.querySelectorAll('body[direction="rtl"] td') returns empty list, but direction:rtl is set via style tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying identify whether the page is using direction *rtl* or *ltr*, i am setting the property via a style tag (using a conditional server side in a template engine)

Example https://jsfiddle.net/ud2f6hre/3/

```html
<body>

</body>
<style>
body {
  direction:rtl;
}

body[direction="rtl"] td{
  color:blue;
}

td {
color:green;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>ABC</td>
 <td>ABCDEF</td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Test"/>
<script>
function test(){
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('body[direction="rtl"] td'))
}
</script>
```

Why does  `document.querySelectorAll('body[direction="rtl"] td')` Retunes an empty NodeList?

As well you can see that the second css selector doesn't change the color to blue

Comment: Well it does seems like direction can not  be targeted... JS or CSS... So I will back you up on `why down-vote`. Cant find my self explanation in documentation... It is represented as CSS property and supported by all browsers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute selectors select elements based on their attributes, not the styles that are applied to them.

You don't have `<body direction="rtl">` in the HTML. The selector doesn't match.

Similar restrictions apply to the [`:dir()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:dir):

> The :dir() pseudo-class uses only the semantic value of the directionality, i.e., the one defined in the document itself. It doesn't account for styling directionality, i.e., the directionality set by CSS properties such as direction.

Comment: the :dir will also only select attributes, thanks anyway